# Travis-ci ignores caching settings for gradle

Tags: java, caching, gradle, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Travis-ci ignores settings that are for caching Gradle directory.
[HERE is my .travis.yml](https://github.com/zimy/wHole/blob/master/.travis.yml) where I setup caching $HOME/.gradle. That was done many commits ago, but it still downloads all Gradle dependencies. You can see build history if you click build status badge at readme.md. I have tried different things, but Travis still do not cache.

I know about environmental variable $GRADLE_USER_HOME which Gradle respects and used it for dependencies. In build setting I set it to $HOME/.gradle and in my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/zimy/questionnaire/blob/master/.travis.yml) I set caching directory to $GRADLE_USER_HOME. But it still not works!

What am I doing wrong? And sorry for explicit links, my reputation is not so big to post more than two links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching isn't yet supported on this infrastructure for public repositories.

You can try out our container setup, which does support it. See the docs for more details: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/

Comment: Thank you! Now Travis uses caching for Gradle!